# Will Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar load on Windows 7?

Tags: toolbar

I can't get the Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar to load on Windows 7, assuming IE 8.   Therefore I am forced to use Firefox and it's toolbar.   Has anyone got the Microsoft toolbar to work on Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works just fine, I just hit F12 and it shows up normally.

Comment: Unfortunately the old toolbar is actually allowed to install on Windows 7 even though it doesn't work, so that threw me for a loop.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the developer toolbar with IE8. Go to the Tools dropdown and you'll find a **MUCH** better set of tools under 'Developer Tools'.

Comment: Unless i've misunderstood @djangofan's question, the IE8 developer toolbar is shipped with IE8... and is the one you find on the Tools menu (e.g. F12)

Comment: I was under the impression that he was talking about the old IE7 Developer Toolbar being installed on Windows 7/IE 8.

Comment: yep, i was talking about the old toolbar.  i had NO IDEA that IE8 had a new toolbar.  what a surprise!